# Office for Mac 2014

Tags: ms-office, microsoft

I have already tried searching, but have not really found any decent resources relating to this.

Office 2011 for Mac is great (their have been many improvements since Office 2008).

Anyway Microsoft has committed to their 3 year release cycle, but there is no beta or other news relating to Office 2014. Does anyone know when they are expecting to release it, or even a preview / beta?

My biggest issue with Office 2011 is its lack of support for retina displays - it simply looks ugly!

Comment: You would think they would release some info about this in their blog http://blog.officeformac.com/.  MacWord UK published a rumor 8 months ago that it would be April 2014.

Comment: Yes! The last post on blog.officeformac.com was in August 5th, 2013 - this makes me wonder if Microsoft have lost direction with Office for Mac.

Comment: Office for Mac does support Retina Displays, including high dpi icons and font rendering. There have been several updates since the original release. Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2742588/en

Answer (score 2):

There's no news on a release date. I'd venture to guess that the Office for Mac is busy working on [Office for iPad](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/02/14/office-ipad-soon/).

As @h3nk mentions, Office 2011 was [updated to support Retina Displays](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2742588/en) (Working fine on the Retina MacBook I'm writing this on).